Unable to connect mongodb cluster to the mongodb connector in elastic search
I am following this guide to try and sync my mongodb cluster to elastic search. I have done all the steps as specified by the guide. I have added the 0.0.0.0/0 IP address to the IP Access List in the cluster yet the connection fails. Please refer to the following screenshot to view the error and my configurations.
Configurations for elastic search
The error message returned by the elastic search:
Connector error:

ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-02.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed
(configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS:
20000.0ms),ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-00.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS:
20000.0ms),ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-01.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description:
<TopologyDescription id: 66551a0ce340cf2c1adaebca, topology_type:
ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription
('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-00.g8vuesu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
Unknown, rtt: None,
error=AutoReconnect('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-00.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017:
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription
('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-01.g8vuesu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
Unknown, rtt: None,
error=AutoReconnect('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-01.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017:
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription
('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-02.g8vuesu.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
Unknown, rtt: None,
error=AutoReconnect('ac-kc4zkek-shard-00-02.g8vuesu.mongodb.net:27017:
connection closed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

I could not find much about it online. I suppose it has something to do with the IP addresses such that the elastic search is unable to access my mongodb cluster but since I have already allowed connections to the cluster from anywhere, I can't seem to understand what's wrong.

That screenshot didn't load for me. "connection closed" can happen if you are connecting without TLS.  Atlas servers will close the connection without any response if TLS is not used.  Check the config to make sure TLS is enabled.

@Joe Thanks for pointing out. That was in fact the issue and also I had to enable Require IP Access List for the Atlas Administration API option in the Atlas organization config to get it to work.

Your connection string is missing the options that your shell command line provides, namely ssl and option to allow invalid certificate.
You could add ?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE after the database name in the string you are passing to MongoClient or see other options for certificate handling on MongoClient page (scroll to "SSL configuration" section)
